# Is possible to induce a maintenance or break with java code?

Tags: anylogic

How can I send all resource units from a resource pool to maintenance or break whenever another event in another block occurs?

I'm looking for something like: resourcePool.startMainteinance()
and write it inside a "On start" box in some other block of the flowchart. Of course then I would need to end the maintenance with something like resourcePool.stopMainteinance() and resume all the tasks the resource units were executing.

Any idea? or some idea to pause manually all resources from executing their task and then resume them?

Note: suspending the agent that seized in the size block with the code SizeBlock.suspend() and SizeBlock.resume() is not an option because the resources have preparation tasks and those tasks also need to be paused.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `Downtime` block that is designed for this setup.

You can control it any way you like. In your case, `myDowntimeblock.startTask(someAgent)` and `stopTask(sameAgent)` work.

Also check the example model named "Maintenance of a Coffee machine": It shows all the other ways of using the block.